# How should be the oil deposit size so that the probability of overflow is 0,001?

Tags: probability

I have the following probability of production of oil

$$f(x) = 4\left(1-x\right)^3\,,  0 <\ x < 1 \\$$

And I need to find a size of the deposit of oil so that the probability of overflow is 0,001, in other words, surpassing its capacity.

In this case if x is between 0 and 1, and I suppose that if producing at full capacity X will be 1, then the deposit will be also 1?

So if the production and deposit size are the same, do I just need to do this:

$$P[X>1]=0,001=1-P[X\le1]=1-\int _0^x\:4\left(1-x\right)^3\:dx$$

An then I solve for X.

Is that right?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Something is missing. What is the meaning of overflow?

Comment: As written below, it means surpassing the capacity of the container of oil produced. In the problem I don't have information about this capacity, so I just suppose that production is proportional to capacity that is x=capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.

I think it might be better to write the capacity as $c$, and you want to find the value of $c$ for which the probability that production $X$ exceeds $c$ is equal to $0.001$, i.e. $\mathbb P(X > c ) = 0.001$, which mean solving

$$1-\int _0^c\:4\left(1-x\right)^3\:dx = 0.001$$ for $c$, or equivalently $\int\limits  _c^1\:4\left(1-x\right)^3\:dx = 0.001$.

Comment: I get 

$$
1-\int_0^c 4(1-x)^3 = (c-1)^4,
$$
of which the four roots that are contained in $[0,1]$ are $c\approx 0.822172$. Is there an analytical form for this expression?

Comment: @Math1000 That is $1-\sqrt[4]{0.001}=1-10^{-3/4}$.  Is that analytical enough for you?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha yields $1 - \frac1{10}^{\frac34}$ for this value of $c$, which follows taking $4^{\mathrm{th}}$ roots gives $\frac1{10}^{\frac34}$ giving the $4^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of unity.

Comment: Indeed, that is "analytical" enough for me :)